# Matplotlib pyplot has partial xtick labels that don't rotate

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

There seems to be some problem with the graph i'm plotting because the x-axis ticks aren't being placed in the right places.

It appears as if there's additional x-axis tick labels being added because they're not conforming to the rules I've been giving them.

[image: Weird x-tick labels not rotating as required]

As you can see above, the major ticks (dates i.e. 2018-09-22) are offset to the left a little bit. This gives the minor ticks (hours i.e. 06:00 AM) some space.

However not all of the minor ticks follow the rotation rule.

### Adjusting the x-axis ticks

Here's the code I used to label the x axis ticks:

```
def label_x_axis(axis, title, dates, figure):
    axis.set_title(title)

    axis.grid(True)

    axis.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
    axis.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator(np.arange(0, 25, 6)))

    axis.set_xticklabels(dates, rotation=60, horizontalalignment='right', minor=True, fontdict=(
        {
            'fontsize': '6',
            'horizontalalignment': 'right'
        }
    ))

    axis.set_xticklabels(dates, rotation=60, horizontalalignment='right', minor=False, fontdict=(
        {
            'fontsize': '8',
            'horizontalalignment': 'right'
        }
    ))

    # Create offset transform by 5 points in x direction
    dx, dy = -12 / 72.0, 0 / 72.0

    # offset = figure.dpi_scale_trans  # matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().translate(dx, dy).rotate(0)

    # matrix
    offset = matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTranslation(dx, dy, figure.dpi_scale_trans)

    axis.xaxis.labelpad = 20

    dayFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
    hourFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M %p')

    axis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dayFmt)
    axis.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(hourFmt)

    # apply offset transform to all x ticklabels.
    for label in axis.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
        label.set_transform(label.get_transform() + offset)
```

Full [Google Colaboratory example here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YBBTTetZK_llkBzfI1CD4gP-hh8Fl8fa).

Comment: @Lucas - There is a Google Colaboratory Python runnable script at the end of the question. Is that not a sufficient MCVE? Or is that not 'minimal' enough? It's not a whole project there, it's really just the plotting code.

Comment: You let matplotlib automatically choose the locations of the ticks. But you manually set the labels for those automatically chosen ticks via `set_ticklabels`. Never use `set_ticklabels` this way. In this case I do not see the reason to use it at all. Just removing it should fix the issue.